# Functional project on netbeans raise an exception in apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

I have this:

- Virtual server with a Windows Server 2008
- Wamp Server 2.4
- Tomcat 7.0

When I run my project in netbeans, it works, I generate the war file and upload to the server.
I use the localhost:8080 manager to starts the project.

When I go to the web, it shows the login page, but when I click on the login button I get an exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider

Any ideas?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowSetProvider` is a Java 7 class. Netbeans may be configured to use Java 7, but Tomcat may not be (perhaps it's using Java 6) - which is why it can't find `RowSetProvider`.

Check that Tomcat is running on Java 7